# Display dialog if a word isn't on a list applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

I'm writing a script that can open and close apps for me. Basically, I type in an app name, and then it opens the app. The only thing is, if the app isn't found, it throws an error and quits. I want to make the script just display a dialog that says something like "App not found".

Here's what I have so far:

```
if userInput contains "Activate " then set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"Activate "}}
if length of userInput is less than or equal to 1 then say (resultString as string)
if length of userInput is greater than or equal to 2 then set resultString to text item 2 of userInput
set openApp to (resultString as string)
if userInput contains "Activate " then set text item delimiters to TID
if userInput contains "Activate " then tell application (openApp as string) to activate
```

BTW, this is just a snippet of my script, which is why there are some undefined variables here.

I tried:

```
set appList to do shell script "cd /Applications; ls"
if openApp is not in appList then display dialog "App not found"
```

Huh, Applescript syntax can be so annoying sometimes.

Thanks.

Comment: But don't you see a popup which ask "Where is xyz?"

Comment: I do, but if I press cancel then I get a weird message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `exists application` but that would also popup a dialog asking "Where is xyz?".

So the best thing you can do seems to be:

```
tell application "Finder" to set appExists to (exists file myApp of folder "Applications" of startup disk)

if not appExists then
    display alert "App not found"
end if
```

Your code is then:

```
if userInput contains "Activate " then set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"Activate "}}
if length of userInput is less than or equal to 1 then say (resultString as string)
if length of userInput is greater than or equal to 2 then set resultString to text item 2 of userInput
set openApp to (resultString as string)

if userInput contains "Activate " then set text item delimiters to TID

tell application "Finder" to set appExists to (exists file (openApp & ".app") of folder "Applications" of startup disk)
if not appExists then
    display alert "App not found"
else
    if userInput contains "Activate " then tell application (openApp as string) to activate
end if
```

Or try to catch the error if the user presses Cancel:

```
try
    if userInput contains "Activate " then tell application (openApp as string) to activate
on error
    display alert "App not found"
end try
```

Comment: Thanks, that last suggestion worked the best for me.